# Cannot use secure cookies with Nginx/Node API

Tags: nginx, cookies, proxy

Let me start by saying that I have thoroughly looked over all information on stackoverflow and the net in regards to this issue, and I have tried several different things to try and get this working.

I am using the package "cookie-session", but when I set secure to true, my cookies are sent with the request (I can see making a login request with Postman) but the session seems like it is not working through the browser. When secure is set to false everything is fine, works as expected.

Let me explain my setup, I have two servers:

**First Server**

- Serverside rendered React App running Node JS
- Running Nginx server
- HTTPS is setup here "www.example.com"
- Proxying any requests made to "www.example.com/api" to second server

**Second Server**

- Node/express app handling API requests
- Running Nginx server

From my understanding, a secure cookie can only be sent if the request is made through HTTPS. Which I believe it is (setup above).

On the second server I have tried using the trust proxy, still no luck:

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1);

app.use(cookieSession({
    maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys: [env.SESSION.COOKIE_KEY],
    secure: true
}));
```

I also figured that this may have something to do with the headers that are sent with Nginx, I have tried many different headers on both servers e.g. (proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme), still no luck.

For the life of me I am not sure what to do from here to get secure cookies working.

Also to mention again that everything works fine with secure set to false. When secure is set to true, I can make a request through Postman to my login and receive my cookies in the request, but it appears the session is not applied on the client.

Could this have anything to do with not having a HTTPS cert installed on the second server? If so, how would I add one anyways as both servers run on the same domain "www.example.com" + proxy /api requests to "www.example.com/api"? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use `app.set('trust proxy', 2);` Because there are two proxies. Also make sure you set Host header.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have set trust proxy to 2, not working just yet. Do you mean to set the Host header on Nginx server 1 or 2? With this: proxy_set_header Host www.example.com?

Comment: I think you'd also need `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https` on nginx-server 2.

Comment: You might also need to set `proxy` to `true` in your session config. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55493317/8620945) for an explanation.