# Nodejs secure cook and HTTPOnly behind proxy server

Tags: node.js, express

In Nodejs with secure cookie and HTTPOnly behind a proxy server.
How does HttpOnly flag and Cookie with Secure flag send it headers to proxy server?

I have been reading and assume I need to enable X-Forward-Proto on my proxy server?

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
}

app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379, client: client, ttl:  3600}),
    key: 'sid',
    secret: 'abcde',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
//    proxy: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 3600000
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and solved it with the help of [this tutorial](https://thewebb.blog/thoughts/2018/using-nginx-express-session-in-production).

You also need to set the `proxy` option to `true` in your session config.
I would suggest doing this with an environment variable expression `process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"`.

```
app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379, client: client, ttl:  3600}),
    key: 'sid',
    secret: 'abcde',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    proxy: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    cookie: {
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 3600000
    }
}));
```

From the [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) docs:

> **proxy**
>
> Trust the reverse proxy when setting secure cookies (via the "X-Forwarded-Proto" header).
>
> The default value is undefined.
>
> true The "X-Forwarded-Proto" header will be used.

Answer (score 0):

The HttpOnly flag is something that is only considered by a HTTP client. A HTTP proxy will just pass on the flag and ignore it.

As long as the client itself connects to the server (or the proxy, if it's a reverse proxy) with HTTPS, it will work.

Comment: So there is a missing parameter, not appear in Google Chrome cookies is normal for those behind the proxy server? HTTP proxy server don't seem to pass on the flag.

Comment: Generic proxy servers shouldn't do this. Maybe yours does. I'd suggest looking into your proxy if this is the case.